# How to create iOS long running backend tasks to report machine status

Tags: ios, iphone

Apple has a list of allowed long running tasks [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)
Besides these tasks, is there anyway that I can create a long running tasks on the back-end, to report the machine's OS version and other metadata to my server, if the app is not closed through multitask UI?

Comment: One of the types listed is "Apps that need to download and process new content regularly", that is, apps that regularly do an http get.  Setup for that, an app can just as easily do a recurring http post.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you sending data from the app to the server, or from the server to the app?

Comment: Hi @almas I am sending collecting data from the local machine and send it to the server regularly.